# Rudin's RCA Theorem $3.14$

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

There are the definitions and theorems which we need for the proof:
[image]
The measure $\mu$ has the properties stated in $2.14$ theorem.

There it is :

[image]

There is the theorem:

For $1\leq p\leq \infty$, $~C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$.
There is the proof:
Define $S$ as the class of all complex, measurable, simple functions on locally compact Hausdorff space X. If $s\in S$, and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $g\in C_c(X)$ such that $g(x)=s(x)$ except on a set of measure $<\epsilon$, and $|g|\leq ||s||_\infty$ (Lusin's theorem).

Hence
$$||g-s||_p \leq 2\epsilon^{1/p}||s||_\infty~.$$
Since $S$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$, this complete the proof.

I Couldn't understand how do we get the last inequality
$$||g-s||_p \leq 2\epsilon^{1/p}||s||_\infty~.$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, $\|g-s\|_p^p=\int_X |g-s|^p dx$, where $X$ is the set of measure at most $\varepsilon$ where the functions differ. So $\|g-s\|_p^p \leq \varepsilon \|g-s\|_\infty^p$ and the RHS is at most $2\|s\|_\infty^p$ according to assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $(2\|s\|_\infty)^p$ on the RHS bound.

Comment: @AnCar why is it the bound?

Comment: you stated $|g|\leq \|s\|_\infty$ as Lusin's theorem. So $\|g-s\|_\infty\leq \|g\|_\infty +\|s\|_\infty\leq 2\|s\|_\infty$.

Comment: @AnCar do we know that essential supremum is positive?

Comment: Are you asking if $\|f\|_\infty\geq 0$ for any function $f$? Then yes, ofc. The sup norm is the supremum of the absolute value of $f$.

Comment: @AnCar Thank you